# Magento admin unable to login with default password using Bitnami hosted on AWS Lightsail VPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento2, bitnami

After setting up the Bitnami Magento 2.1.2 VPS on AWS Lightsail, the admin login is not successful with default credentials as well unable to reset the MySQL root password.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of Magento CLI to create new admin user with the following command, then login to admin area and change password of the original admin user.

```
<path_to_magento> php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --admin-email=admin@example.com --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin
```

Note:

- you need **php** command before the whole syntax
- **path_to_magento** refers to hosting path e.g. ~/apps/magento/htdocs$

Comment: For bitnami's magento docker image, `path_to_magento` is `/bitnami/magento/`